# Getting the Tomcat StandardContext within Spring.io

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I would like to access some files that are not below the document root of the server.

I have this Bean

```
  @Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
       TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(){
```

And then I have found the class

```
org.apache.catalina.core
Class StandardContext

java.lang.Object
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase
org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleMBeanBase
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
```

which implements the method:

```
public void setAliases(String aliases)
Set the current alias configuration. The list of aliases should be of the form "/aliasPath1=docBase1,/aliasPath2=docBase2" where aliasPathN must include a leading '/' and docBaseN must be an absolute path to either a .war file or a directory.
```

But how can I get the StandardContext in my Spring MVC implementation?

I deploy my server by creating a war.file that includes Tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the solution I finallay went with:

```
 @Bean
 public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
          TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(){    
          @Override
           protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {

           ...  

           StandardContext sContext = (StandardContext) context;  
           sContext.setAliases( "/files=/home/myuser/files");
          }
       };

       ...

  return tomcat;
}
```